# jpg displaying differently in Firefox and IE

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, jpeg

I've recently been working on a website that uses a mix of png and jpg files. I used a few jpgs because of size issues. Everything was working great, until I tested it in IE. In all versions of IE that I tested it in, the jpgs were lighter, and the colors didn't match with my pngs.

Firefox:

[image]

IE:

[image]

As you can see, this is a bit of a problem. Is there a way to correct this? I can't seem to find much information on why this is happening. If it makes any difference, I used GIMP 2.6 to export all my images.

Comment: What settings did you use to export the jpeg?

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at JPEG export properties in GIMP. Maybe it assign a color profile to your image, but IE (or Firefox) ignores it?

> Color profile
>
> Many JPEG files embed an ICC color
>   profile (color space). Commonly used
>   color profiles include sRGB and Adobe
>   RGB. Because these color spaces use a
>   non-linear transformation, the dynamic
>   range of an 8-bit JPEG file is about
>   11 stops. However, many applications
>   are not able to deal with JPEG color
>   profiles and simply ignore them.

Comment: I think I ran into this while researching.. how would I not embed a color profile though?

Comment: Actually I dunno. Photoshop ask for this when saving to JPEG in a save dialog.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in older versions of Firefox that have been upgraded. I noticed this too, but the other way. When I export a RAW photo as JPEG from Lightroom, it looks darker in Firefox than it does in Lightroom, but it looks right in IE or the Picasa Photo Viewer.

It was fixed in "newer" versions (3.5 or 4, not sure which), but only for clean installs. If you first installed Firefox before then, you need to enable gfx.color_management.enablev4 in about:config and restart FF.

I'm using Firefox 17, but started on this computer with 3 or 3.5, and just realized I had this problem. Changing that setting fixed it. However, that setting is not needed to be enabled on newer installs to display images correctly (it is disabled by default).

More information here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_management#Application_level
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_management#cite_note-10.

Answer (score 0):

Your application should offer you a "weight" option or similar when exporting JPEGs, giving four choices, a global one plus red, green, and blue. Try setting that to the global one.

Comment: Rubbish, I was thinking about palette based GIFs. Sorry. In JPEG, there is only subsampling but as far as I know, that won't affect colours this badly...